# RTK Query failing to fetch new data after mutation

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to use RTK query to fetch data from Firestore using the `queryFn`. The problem I'm having is that I'm developing a multiwizard, where the fields in the form are initialised with data straight from RTK Query.

Update an input field with a mutation in step 1
Go to step 2
Go back to step 1 (fetch is rejected with a ConditionError, please see attached log)

```
export const userApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'userApi',
    baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
    tagTypes: ['User'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getUser: builder.query<Customer, string>({
            async queryFn(userId) {
                try {
                    const docSnapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', userId));
                    const customer = docSnapshot.data() as Customer;
                    return { data: customer };
                } catch (err) {
                    return { error: err };
                }
            },
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{type: 'User', id: result.id }]
            
        }),
        updateUser: builder.mutation<{ success: boolean }, { userId: string; user: Partial<UserInfo> }>({
            async queryFn(payload) {
                const { userId, user } = payload;
                try {
                    // Note: Id is same for both. Have also tried replacing with 'LIST'
                    const res = await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', userId), { ...user });
                    return { data: { success: true } };
                } catch (err) {
                    return { error: err ? err : null };
                }
            },
            invalidatesTags:  (result, error, { userId }) => [{ type: 'User', id: userId}],
        })
    })
});

export const { useGetUserQuery, useUpdateUserMutation } = userApi;
```

I've also tried just using `User` for the providesTag/invalidatesTags.

I'm trying to figure out why the 2nd query, after going back to step 1 of the form fails to retrieve the data I've just updated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating rtk from 1.8.5 to 1.9.0

Seems like there was a bug

> invalidateTags works correctly when dealing with persisted query
> state.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.9.0